# asp.net using async in a controller when calling a method to get all Users in a service

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-identity-2

I am struggling to understand async and await when applied to methods called from a controller with async action.

I havent been able to find an example that shows this in a format I can use.

I have a service class with a method called GetAllUsers():

```
   public class UserAdminService : IUserAdminService
{
    private JobsDbContext _context;
    protected readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

    public UserAdminService(JobsDbContext context, UserManager<User> userManager)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<IList<UserAdminIndexViewModel>> GetAllUsers()
    {
        List<User> Users = await _userManager.Users.ToListAsync();
        ...
        return 

    }
```

Users are ApplicationUser - Entity 3 just renamed to User.

I intend to use a loop to convert the Users list to a view model and return it to the controller.

I am not sure if I need to have the service as async but thought this was the correct way.

With regard to the line:

```
List<User> Users = await _userManager.Users.ToListAsync();
```

I am getting an error on the "=" sign - "Invalid expression" so I have failed to structure this correctly. Further I am gettting an error on the ";" saying "Identifier expected ; expected" while there is already one there.

How do I structure this line correctly to get all users via UserManager and also how do I structure the return (the usermodel equated with the values from this list - Users) in an async context?

Comment: The code looks fine to me (the last line would just be `return Users;`). Try to reduce to a minimal, reproducible example, and you'll probably find the problem along the way.

Comment: Thanks Stephen.. To fix this I ended up closing the project and reopening it. The error disappeared.